# How to boost a certain field at query time in solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm trying to boost a certain field at query time using the solr config file. i know i can use the qf to specify a list of fields using the field^boost syntax but then i do not want my field to automatically be included in the search fields when doing general queries.

Thus suppose i want the authors field boosted by 4.0, but doing a default query for "something" and having the title and body in the qf both with boost 2.0, i would get a parsed query like   (title:something^2.0 OR body:something^2) on "something" and (title:something^2.0 OR body:something^2 authors:john^4.0) on "something authors:john". I want this field to be boosted on query time , not on index.

edit : all i came up with till now was write another search-component that attaches the boost to the field parsing the raw qString then passes it forward to the query component. I would still appreciate any input on weather this can be achieved using just the predefined solr config settings

If it matters any i am using the edismax query parser

thanks in advance

Comment: What your describing sounds exactly like an index-time field boost.  Why must it be applied at query time?

Comment: index time boosting takes extra memory as far as i know (you have to have norms on that certain field) and i want to avoid that scenario.

Comment: Yes, what you are asking for is intended to be accomplished using norms.  It would be reasonable to assume that indexing norms is the most performant implementation available to you, unless you have reason to believe otherwise.  Have you currently set up your index to omit norms?  If so, then you implicitly lose the ability to add the style of boost your referring to, as well as field-length based scoring.  If not, adding field level boosts will not impact memory usage, since you are already storing norms (field boosts are stored in the same byte as length norms which are indexed by default).